# How to use dependency injection in Spek tests

Tags: spring, testing, kotlin

I am implementing simple microservice using Kotlin, Spring and Spek. I want to test my repository but I wonder how can I inject repo into spek test case. Every example or tutorial base on creating new reference like this:

```
object SampleTest : Spek({
    describe("a calculator") {
        val calculator = SampleCalculator()

        it("should return the result of adding the first number to the second number") {
            val sum = calculator.sum(2, 4)
            assertEquals(6, sum)
        }

        it("should return the result of subtracting the second number from the first number") {
            val subtract = calculator.subtract(4, 2)
            assertEquals(2, subtract)
        }
    }
})
```

To summup I dont want to do sth like this:

```
val calculator = SampleCalculator()
```

I want to achieve this

```
@Autowired
val calculator: SampleCalculator
```

but I cant to that becasue I cant autowire service into local variable.. Any solutions ? I am new in kotlin and spek.

Comment: A workaround that I can immediately suggest trying is a local [`object` expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions) with the `@Autowired` property in it. Does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Try it with [lateinit](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties):

```
@Autowired
lateinit var calculator: SampleCalculator
```

Comment: did you find any solution for the above question ? @user3528733

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [spek-spring-extension](https://github.com/spekframework/spek-spring-extension) project at GitHub, there's a way to inject beans from Spring context:

**Spring Extension for Spek**

This is a proof of concept for writing spring integration tests in Spek

**Limitations**

Currently, only injecting beans is supported.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = arrayOf(MyConfiguration::class))
object MySpec: Spek({
    val context = createContext(MySpec::class)
    val foo = context.inject<Foo>()
    // val foo: Foo by context.inject()

    it("blah blah blah") {
        foo.doSomething()
    }
})
```

**Issues**

Spring's TestContext framework makes assumptions on how tests are structured which is incompatible with Spek, which means we can't use TestContextManager (we can but it will be very hackish).

Comment: This example is no longer valid, functions and logic doesn't exist in Spek `2.0.10`